# usage of 'while' and 'when'

Tags: conjunctions, past-simple, past-continuous

> I met many interesting people while I was living in Vancouver.

Can I change the sentence above to the sentences below? Do they have slightly different meanings?

> I met many interesting people when I lived in Vancouver.

or

> I met many interesting people when I was living in Vancouver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both perfectly fine.  "While" may have a bit more of a sense of the occurrence happening over a length of time, i.e. *during* the condition given, and accordingly, "when" sounds a bit like it describes a single point in time.  But if so, it is very faint; the context overrides this sense easily.

Answer (score 2):

*X while Y* means that Y is true or applies for the entire duration X happened.

*X when Y* means Y is true because of or as a result of X.

> I met many interesting people when I lived in Vancouver.

You're implying somewhat more strongly here than the other sentence that if someone else goes to Vancouver, they will also meet interesting people.