# Is the use of the conjunction " While" at the beginning of this sentence correct? While hearing the bad news, l told everybody in the village

Tags: word-choice, syntax

Is it correct to use the conjunction "**While**" at the beginning of the following sentence?

**While hearing** the bad news, l told everybody in the village.

I think "**While**" is not correct, so we could use "**On**" or "**After**" instead.

Am l correct?

Comment: "On" or "after" would be better, Note, though, that "while" is a preposition in modern grammar, not a conjunction.

Comment: ***While*** and ***when*** are often equivalent and interchangeable. The cited example isn't remotely idiomatic with ***while***, but ***when*** works fine - provided we switch from the continuous to Simple Past with explicit subject: ***When I heard**  the bad news, l told everybody in the village.* In that context, we know pragmatically that ***when*** means "immediately after" rather than "at the same time" (a shift in meaning which is only possible with ***when***, not ***while***).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When / while + past continuous/simple.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328990/when-while-past-continuous-simple) Also [usage of 'while' and 'when'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210973/usage-of-while-and-when) and others.

Comment: In this type of sentence, *while* often means two things happening at the same time, for example - *"While washing the dishes, I listened to the radio."* Your sentence means that you were telling everyone in the village at the same time as you were hearing the bad news. Only likely if you were doing a simultaneous translation in front of the crowd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On" is definitely better, "while" implies that you were telling people at exactly the same time as you were hearing it which sounds very odd. "After" also works but explicitly implies a time relationship, whereas "on" just implies one thing leading to another causally, which I think is the intention behind using "while".

Comment: You're right, WHILE seems very odd. How can someone listening at the bad news and tells other people at the same time.

Comment: So you knew the answer all along!

Comment: Actually,  l wasn't sure of the answer, so l wanted confirmation.